# Can the standard deviation be as large as the value itself

Tags: statistics

While tutoring, a statistics student presented me with this problem which appears to have an unrealistic standard deviation value.

"the mean age of women is 21 years old.  A random sample of 30 is selected from this population. Two thirds of the population is between 18 and 24 years old.  What is the probability that a person selected at random from the population is 17 years old."

To compute the standard deviation I used the standard error formula of

$$E=\frac{(Z_66.6%)(\sigma)}{\sqrt{n}}(\sigma)$$

using .97 for Z and 3 for error and 30 for n, I solved for the standard deviation

$$3=\frac{(.97)(\sigma)}{\sqrt{30}}$$

this yields a standard deviation of about 17?

So then to compute the probability that I select one person who is 17 years old would be

$$Z=\frac{17-21}{16.94}$$

which yields a z value of -.23 and that is around 42% so i conclude that there is a 42% chance of selecting a girl that is 17.

So my question is,  can the standard deviation be almost as large as the value itself?

Comment: As for what you actually *asked*: if negative values are realistic in the model, absolutely; we talk about normal distributions with mean zero all the time, for example. If negative values are not realistic in the model (as in your example) then this is not really consistent with the normal approximation, since there will be a significant probability of negative values. Now as it happens your question may be based on an error...

Comment: Something is wrong with your calculation.  If you take a normal distribution with mean $21$ and st. dev. $3$ then $68\%$ of the values lie within $3$ of the mean...hence between $24$ and $18$.  As $68\%$ is quite near two thirds, sigma must be very close to $3$.

Comment: As lulu has pointed out, your mistake is that they are talking about the *population* standard deviation, so you don't need the $\sqrt{n}$ factor in there. That is for the standard deviation of the sample mean, which is a different quantity.

Comment: of course,  love you guys

Answer (score 1):

An error in your calculation: you're using the standard error of the mean (which divides by $\sqrt n$) when you should use just the plain standard deviation. You can see that 42% is the wrong answer for the probability of 17 *or younger*, since only 1/6 of the population is below 18.

Comment: thanks grand chat, Im a little rusty in stats